# Como cambiar de una vista a otra con un input

Tags: html, css, html5

¿Se puede pasar de una página a otra a través de un input?

```html
<input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
```

Intenté ponerle un:

```
src="registro.html"
```

o un:

```
<href="registro.html">
```

Pero no me redirigen a otra página web.

Comment: Puedes encerrar al `input` en una etiqueta `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como menciona @fedex7501, puedes envolver un `input` o un `button` u otro elemento en una etiqueta `<a href="url">elemento</a>`, la cual, según la documentación de MDN:

> El Elemento HTML Anchor  crea un enlace a otras páginas de internet, archivos o ubicaciones dentro de la misma página, direcciones de correo, o cualquier otra URL.

```html
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">
  <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
</a>
```

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) encuentras la documentación del elemento `anchor` en MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que si estás utilizando un `<input>`, tendrás un formulario con un el botón correspondiente para enviar los datos, en tal caso, podrías utilizar el atributo `action` que tiene la etiqueta `<form>`, y puedes ponerle la dirección que desees:

```
<form action="registro.html">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Esto buscara el fichero `registro.html` dentro de tu proyecto actual